# Can gnosis-relay-service relay full signed transactions?

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis

Let's say we have 2/2 signatures all signed.

**Could this be broadcasted to the relay service and someone else picks it up just to execute?**

If so, how would you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly we decommissioned our Relay service some time ago. While we created some POCs is not something that we currently have in our roadmap.

Answering your question:

**Could this be broadcasted to the relay service and someone else picks it up just to execute?**

Yes, in the future, if the Relayer service is running again, you will need 3 things:

- At least the minimum number of signatures required to be able to execute the transaction (threshold).
- A small amount of Wrapped Ether in your Safe (Minimum 0.1 WETH) (the Wrapped native token required depends on the chain that you are using, example Wrapped Ether in Mainnet & Wrapped xDai in Gnosis Chain).
- You must give permission to our Relay Smart Contract to use a certain amount of your Wrapped Ether. (function approve(address spender, uint256 amount))

After that you can use our Relay Service specifying the `safeTxHash` of the transaction that you want to be executed by our Relayer.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, 
I heard from another gnosis team member that gnosis safe will continue the relay service. Just to make sure:
Can you just confirm that the gnosis relay you mean is (https://github.com/5afe/safe-relay-service) and this will be deprecated? 

And that safe-relay service (https://safe-client.safe.global/index.html) is different and will continue?